# Preserving the type of a variable after going through a function without generics in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

Is there any way in TypeScript to type the following `fn` function so that TypeScript would still know that `result` is of type `'hello'`?

```
const hello = 'hello' // hello is of type 'hello'

const fn = (x: unknown) => x

const result = fn(hello) // result is of type unknown
```

With a generic, it is possible to pass the type:

```
const hello = 'hello' // hello is of type 'hello'

const fnWithGeneric = <T>(x: T) => x

const result = fnWithGeneric<typeof hello>(hello) // result is of type 'hello'
```

But with generics, if there are multiple parameters, I end up passing multiple generics that are juste `typeof` the parameters and it creates a lot of noise. Is there a better way to do this?

See this [TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0#code/MYewdgzgLgBAFgUwDZJDAvDA5IlIsBQBoksAZmBjABQAeAXDAK5gDWYIA7mAJQYB8MWkRLQYFAOoBLKHADiCMAgBOU4FQA8AFX51GWvukHDi4McoQQmSKAEYqFarlQ9TpGBas2ATA7DTZBSVVYA0oAE8ABwQQMnhkVF1nEFcCAHo0mAAJEAA3FRg8gs9rOxgAQzAAEw9LUt8oNAgEBGY2Dm4K6uxkwiA) and hover on `result`.

Answer (score 2):

When doing test, i can see that fn returns is typeof string.
I guess you are using another more complex object ?

You do not have to add the type of hello, type of hello would be inferred.

```
const result = fnWithGeneric(hello); 
console.log('typeof result = ' + typeof result); // string
console.log('typeof result = ' + hello.constructor.name); // String
```

You also might think about add type return :

```
const fnWithGeneric = <T>(x: T): T => x;
```

Without generics, i have tried this, and it looks to work :

```
const fn = (x: unknown) => x as typeof x;
```

Comment: You mean *without generics*. The `(x: unknown) => x as typeof x` is still Typescript. Good answer, though ;)

Comment: I am not talking about the runtime result of a `typeof`, which is indeed `string` in any case. I am talking about the static type analysis (what your editor says the type is when you hover the variable for instance). I added a [link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0#code/MYewdgzgLgBAFgUwDZJDAvDA5IlIsBQBoksAZmBjABQAeAXDAK5gDWYIA7mAJQYB8MWkRLQYFAOoBLKHADiCMAgBOU4FQA8AFX51GWvukHDi4McoQQmSKAEYqFarlQ9TpGBas2ATA7DTZBSVVYA0oAE8ABwQQMnhkVF1nEFcCAHo0mAAJEAA3FRg8gs9rOxgAQzAAEw9LUt8oNAgEBGY2Dm4K6uxkwiA) to a TS playground :) Adding `as typeof x` did not solve the issue to preserve the type.